# Regex Replace failing, and I can't catch the reason?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I use this regex patter with `.match()` and it works as expected. However, trying to make it work with `.replace()` appears to be failing, and I can't catch the reason. Maybe I need some new eyes..

```
(function(){
var testRegex   = /^\/Monkey\/tooth\d+\/$/g;
var testStr = '/Monkey/tooth8/';
var testMatch   = testStr.match(testRegex,'');
var newString   = testStr.replace(testRegex,'');
alert(newString);
if(nullCheck(testMatch) == false){alert('false');}else{alert('true');}
})()
```

I would expect the alert to alert an empty box but it just alerts the the same thing as testStr. What am I missing from this, I ultimately want to get rid of string in the event it exists. Example output

```
/Monkey/Tooth10/Hello/World => Hello/World

/Monkey/Tooth10/GoodBye/World => GoodBye/World
```

Comment: When I run that code the alert box is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `^` and `$` to avoid whole string match that assert position at start and end of the string respectively.

You can try

```
\/Monkey\/tooth\d+\/
```

OR just remove `$`

```
^\/Monkey\/tooth\d+\/
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lL6sL3/1)

Sample code: (use `i` modifier for ignore-case match)

```
var re = /\/Monkey\/tooth\d+\//gi;
var str = '/Monkey/Tooth10/Hello/World';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);

var matchedString = str.match(re);
```

---

#### [JavaScript String match() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

The `match()` method searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.

**Note:** If the regular expression does not include the `g` modifier (to perform a global search), the `match()` method will return only the first match in the string.

This method returns `null` if no match is found.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since Im still familiarizing with regex patterns I notice you added an I after the g? also, the added / before the g? Also could you elaborate on why avoid or dont use the ^ or $? I only ask cause I have seen so many examples in time using them. Also would this pattern be good for .match() as well?

Comment: why you need `match` first, Simply call `replace` if matched then it will be replaced.

Comment: I have match in play somewhere else, as I need to actually keep the string intact, however from the UI level I don't need my users seeing that particular bit of the string, So I use match for a couple things if it exists I do a couple things that alters the end runs behavior, but in the case of replace its purely a cosmetic need for the front end

Comment: Just try it `console.log(str.match(re));` return `null` or `undefined` if not matched otherwise return the matched string.

Comment: Very cool, thank you. On a slight more subjective note, do you know any good resources for understanding regex better? Books? Articles? other?

Comment: Starts from [rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html) where it's explained in detail with best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes from your regex. So instead of `var testRegex = '/^\/Monkey\/tooth\d+\/$/g';` use:

```
var testRegex = /^\/Monkey\/tooth\d+\/$/g;
```

In Javascript regex literal is not quoted OR else `RegExp` object is used.

Comment: I've used it with and without, fails either way when trying to replace. I should have corrected my example though. Cause that was just a try for wth :-)

Comment: After quote removal `testStr.replace(testRegex,'');` gives empty string.